# Date Parsing error when hosting in IIS

Tags: vb.net, date, .net-4.0, type-conversion

i have the following date parsing in vb.net :

```
Dim SDate As Date = Format("yyyy-MM-dd", date1)
```

it's worked fine in development , but when i host the application in IIS .Net v(4.0) it give me the following:

```
Conversion from string 2012-06-28 to type 'Date' is not valid.
```

.....

i tried many forms of date parsing , **all of them worked fine in Development**

but when I host them in IIS , it always give me error

thanks in advance,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found great article about my problem

http://lesession.blogspot.com/2008/07/wrong-date-format-on-your-iis-website.html

the solution was to put the following in web.config:

```
  <globalization culture="en-GB"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the method -  `Date.Parse`, `Date.TryParse`, `Date.ParseExact` to parse string to date type.

Comment: I used Date.ParseExact(date1, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)....  it gave me .. **Conversion from string 07/01/2012 to type 'Date' is not valid.**

Comment: when I tried ** Date.Parse(date1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)**  it gave me in run time  **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Comment: when i used  ` Date.ParseExact(date1, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)` it gave me **The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.UmAlQuraCalendar.**